# Why does Rails sanitize() perform differently in rspec than in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rspec, actioncontroller

In my `config/initializers` I added the following to the `String` class:

```
class String
  def sanitize(options={ tags: %w(div p span strong b em i br ol ul li) })
    ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self, options)
  end
end
```

On my local development site, this converts all disallowed tags to encoded html, so

```
"<span><img src=\"nonexistent.png\" onerror=\"alert('This alert should not be shown');\"></span><p>Build something</p>"
```

becomes

```
"<span>&lt;img src=\"nonexistent.png\" onerror=\"alert('This alert should not be shown');\"/&gt;</span><p>Build something</p> "
```

But in rspec, calling the same method on the same string results in:

```
"<span></span><p>Build something</p>"
```

It is not encoding the image tag anymore; it is just stripping the tag out altogether. What is the cause of this different behavior in a model spec than in a model?

Comment: Show the code you're talking about that's calling this `String#sanitize` method, in both your own code and in rspec (or indicate if you meant that your same app code when called from rspec results in the whole element being removed).

Comment: It's the same code obviously: `str.sanitize`. But the reason for it was ultimately because a front end rich text editor was implementing html encoding before sending it to the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to know.  Easy to find out.  Mostly: don't do that.

Hard to know:
Something else is clobbering your sanitize method or you're clobbering someone else's?

Easy to find out:
Write a test.  Set a breakpoint before calling sanitize.  Step into it and keep stepping.  You'll probably see what's going on pretty quickly.

Don't do that:

1. Other things either add that method or you can call sanitize from something else.  I'm not sure what the right solution is for you, but probably a controller or helper method `sanitize(string, options)` is better than doing what you've done.  After all, that's what you're calling.
2. If you have to add a method, don't open the class and clobber like you've done:

```
module StringSanitizer
  def sanitize(...)
    super # if appropriate - see if it already exists in the class or if something else has already added it
    ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self, options)
  end
end
String.prepend(StringSanitizer)
```

Comment: There is no sanitize method on String: `String.instance_methods.include? :sanitize # => false`

Comment: The rest still stands: Don't do that.  Debug it if you really have to do that.

Comment: Thanks @kwerle. I commented the cause above, but I appreciate your answer as it ultimately led me to a better implementation: a module with a `before_save` that receives attr args from the model.

Comment: @Ando That's great!  But as the saying goes: "Pics or it didn't happen."  Answer your own question here with the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came with following @kwerle 's recommendations:

```
module Sanitizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def sanitizable(*attributes)
      before_save do |record|
        attributes.each do |attribute|
          record[attribute] = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(record[attribute], tags: %w(p span strong b em i br ol ul li))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and this can be used in a model with:

```
include Sanitizable
sanitizable :subtitle, :description
```